# Python's Pool.map() lists items very irregularly and slowing down towards the end

Tags: python, multiprocessing

How exactly does a pool of 60 workers receive items from an input list? Is every 60th item put on a new list, which is fed into the spawned pool worker? The way they process things seems that there is some order to input, but it is not quite in the right sequence and the bigger the input list (the longer it runs), the more out of order they seem to be processed.

When I have input lists of size 1000 or 10000, the time it takes for script to run increases linearly with the list size. But as I go over 100,000, then it appears that the processing slows down after a while. The closer it is to the end, the slower it is, almost as if some workers already stopped running and I am down from 60 works to only a few. My workers do network requests and perhaps some finish faster due to lower latency.

I think I can solve this slowing down by splitting my input list into smaller chunks and starting my workers several times consecutively. I would still like to know, how to explain this weird output order that the following toy example causes:

```py
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import random

latencies = [0.70, 0.75, 0.80, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1.0, 1.05, 1.1, 1.15, 1.2, 1.25, 1.30]


def test_workload(number):
    print(number)
    time.sleep(random.choice(latencies))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = timer()
    list_input = list(range(1, 100000))
    p = Pool(60)
    p.map(test_workload, list_input)
    end = timer()
    print(f"Task completed in {(end - start)} seconds for {len( list_input)} items.")
```

Small part of console output when processing a list of 100000 items with 60 workers:

```
18339
25023
1663
6665
17930
828
4578
16672
20845
2497
412
12092
```

With my toy example, I wasn’t able to reproduce the slowing down towards the end of the list when running 1k, 10k and 100k list items so I'll be happy too learn more about `Pool.map()`. I'll test 1M when I am afk.

Is there a way to regularly output the number of workers in the pool, that are still running? I remembered I can count them in Process Explorer and will try that.

Comment: The tasks will be started in order, but in a pool, you have no control over what order they finish.  There's no reason why processing should slow down, no matter how many tasks you run.  And you shouldn't need to convert the `range` to a list.  Just leave it as an iterator.

Comment: You know why the order is wacky, don't you?  It's your random latencies.  Each worker will handle a chain of requests.  Some workers will be cursed by always choosing the longer latencies, so they will print lower numbers than the workers who get short latencies.  Plus, you're running 60 processes on a machine with, maybe, 8 processors, so there's going to be a lot of competition, and some processes won't win as often.

Comment: @TimRoberts You said, "...but in a pool, you have no control over what order they finish." True enough, but what are you contrasting that with? If you start two `Process` instances in parallel, you also have no control over the order in which they finish. But nevertheless, even with a pool you do have control over the order in which results are returned, e.g. in task-submission order when using `map`  *as far as the return values are concerned* or completion order when using `apply_async` with a callback.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand what is actually going on:

1. You are submitting (100000 - 1) = 99999 tasks to a pool size of 60.
2. You did not specify a *chunksize* argument to the `map` method call, so it defaults to `None`.
3. Therefore a *chunksize* value will be computed for you. In this case that value will be 417.
4. The 99999 tasks will be placed on the input task queue as 239 chunks of tasks of size 417 and one smaller task chunk of size 336.
5. Each idle process in the pool selects from the input task queue selects the next chunk of tasks and executes all the sub-tasks in the chunk before becoming idle again.
6. Because of the random element introduced into how long any task takes to run, it follows that the time to execute a chunk takes a random amount of time.

But to keep the math simple, let's imagine we are down to the final 60 chunks that need to be executed and miraculously all 60 processes in the pool have become idle at the same time and so each process starts to work on one of the  remaining chunks at the same time. Even if every task took the same amount of time to run, you can see that the process running that last, smaller chunk of size 336 will finish first and will remain idle offering no assistance in executing any of the other chunks. But when you consider that all these chunks can vary wildly in their execution time, you will have processes completing their chunks one by one becoming idle and doing nothing to help the other processes left in the pool running chunks. That is, when a processor becomes idle for good because there are no more chunks on the task input queue, there are still potentially hundreds if not thousands of tasks left to process.

Try re-running with an explicit *chunksize* value of 1. In general, when you have tasks of more-or-less fixed running time, this might increase the total running time of the program since it now involves more reads and writes to the task queues. But this should avoids the above problem and you should see all the processors active until the final 60 tasks when they will drop out one by one.

Comment: Did you try re-running with a *chunksize* of 1? Did this make sense?